# android.intent.category.DEFAULT might be making Trouble

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, manifest, dropbox

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.clmitchell.ewtraker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
android:installLocation="auto" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
    android:maxSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true"
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="320" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <activity
        android:name=".ActSplash"
        android:label="@string/title_act_splash" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".pSectors.ActSectors"
        android:label="@string/title_act_sectors" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ActDBMaint"
        android:label="@string/title_act_dbmaint" />
    <activity
        android:name=".pSectors.ActSectorDetail"
        android:label="@string/title_act_sectord" />
    <activity
        android:name=".pAlliances.ActAlliances"
        android:label="@string/title_act_alliances" />
    <activity
        android:name=".pAlliances.ActDlgAddAllc"
        android:label="@string/title_act_addallc" />
    <activity
        android:name=".pAlliances.ActAllianceDetail"
        android:label="@string/title_act_allianced" />
    <activity
        android:name=".pPlayers.FrgActPlayers"
        android:label="@string/title_act_players" />
    <activity
        android:name=".pPlayers.ActDlgAddPlyr"
        android:label="@string/title_act_addplyr" />
    <activity
        android:name=".pPlayers.FrgActPlyrDtl"
        android:label="@string/title_act_plyrd" />
    <activity
        android:name=".pBases.FrgActBases"
        android:label="@string/title_act_bases" />
    <activity
        android:name=".pBases.ActDlgAddBase"
        android:label="@string/title_act_addbase" />
    <activity
        android:name=".pBases.FrgActBaseDtl"
        android:label="@string/title_act_based" />
    <activity
        android:name=".pBases.ActPlyrBases"
        android:label="@string/title_act_pbases" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ActDropBox"
        android:label="@string/title_act_dbox" />
    <activity android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAuthActivity" />
    <activity
      android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
      android:launchMode="singleTask" >
      <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="db-1njkuxldz7m7g4j" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
      android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="false"
      android:label="Dropbox Sync" />
    <service
        android:name=".CtlSplash"
        android:exported="false"/>   
    <service
        android:name=".pSectors.CtlSectors"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <service
        android:name=".pAlliances.CtlAlliances"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <service
        android:name=".pPlayers.CtlPlayers"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <service
        android:name=".pBases.CtlBases"
        android:exported="false"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I was in the act of setting up DropBox support when i noticed that my first two Activities (ActSectors & ActSectorDetail) were no longer responding to the menu item that loads the activity ActDBMaint. My app is VERY SQLite-intensive, so i suspect that the added entries for DropBox in the Manifest may be causing some trouble.

Here's the Logcat from the moment the menu item for ActDBMaint is pressed:

```
04-02 12:52:09.195: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
04-02 12:52:09.225: W/EGL_emulation(795): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-02 12:52:11.935: W/InputMethodManagerService(288): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40dc0508 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@40f06190
```

I've read the following [articles](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html); but I fail to see how they apply to my app.

I'm a noob at Android programming, so I would appreciate some advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying the 2 activities fail to launch when clicking their corresponding menu item in '`ActDBMaint`?

Comment: How are you invoking those default classses ,you are not specifying intent names for that.

Comment: To Jeshurun: The Activity ActDBMaint will not load when called from the activities ActSectors and ActSectorDetail.

Comment: To Arju: The class ActDBMaint is on the menu of nearly every other activity (dialog activities such as ActDlgAddPlyr being the exception).

Comment: Do You observe any error in LogCat then trying to load these activities?

Comment: I've added the LogCat.

Comment: There's really not enough here to troubleshoot.  I see nothing obviously amiss in the manifest.  Do you have some code to post?

Comment: what you are tring to do..??? explain in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the ids/names of the menu items (the menu xml entry and the listing in the activities' onOptionsItemSelected()) didn't match!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that these two Activities are the only ones in the package 'pSectors'. Did you by chance move the actual classes to a different package?